# How to stub a public setter method for a protected property in Mockery

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I want to stub a public setter method (`setA()`) for a protected property in the same class I am testing, but I am getting this error:

***Cannot access protected property Mockery_2_Foo::$a***

My goal is just to unit-test `method1`, but that method is calling `setA`, so I am not sure how I can stab out `setA` so it won't in any way interfere with the unit-test result for `method1`.

```
class Foo {
    protected $a;
   
    public function setA($val) { 
        $this->a =  $val * 2;
    }
 
   
    public function method1($val) {  
        $this->setA($val);
        return $val * 4;
   }
   ............
}

/**
 * @coversDefaultClass Foo
 */
class FooTest {
 
    public function setUp(): void { 
        $this->foo = Mockery::mock(Foo::class) 
            ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods()
            ->makePartial();  
    }
    /** 
     * @covers ::method1 
     */
    
    public function testMethod1() {
        $this->foo->shouldReceive('setA')
            ->set('a', 4);  
        $this->assertEquals(8, $this->foo->method1(2));  
    }
    ..........
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockery can only set public properties (see [docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html#setting-public-properties)).

I don't really get what you are trying to do, but maybe it's just because of your simplified example. Instead of using Mockery you could just create an anonymous class that extends `Foo` and adds the desired behavior:

```
class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMethod1()
    {
        $foo = new class extends Foo {
            public function setA($val)
            {
                $this->a = 4;
            }
        };

        self::assertEquals(8, $foo->method1(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: my goal is to just to test `method1`. but that method is calling `setA`, so I am looking for a way to stab out setA so it will not in any way affect this unit test for `method1`.

Comment: In this case, is it also acceptable to just use `$this->foo->shouldReceive('setA')` (without ->set() expectation  )  or is your solution the only way I should be running this unit test? Thanks

Comment: @Edville From the example you gave, I'd say the purpose of `method1` is to return the input value multiplied by four. And that's what I would test. I don't see a reason to stub out `setA` as it doesn't change the outcome of `method1` in any way.